# How to locate a free/delete mismatch reported by Valgrind in a multithreaded program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, valgrind

Here is the Valgring report:

```
==14546== Thread 5:
==14546== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==14546==    at 0x490555D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:235)
==14546==    by 0x3BF7EFAA8F: free_mem (in /lib64/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
==14546==    by 0x3BF7EFA581: __libc_freeres (in /lib64/tls/libc-2.3.4.so)
==14546==    by 0x4802676: _vgw_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==14546==  Address 0x4DC4EE0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

How can I know which thread is it as the thread number varies from one execution to another ? Will [assigning names to my threads](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html#drd-manual.naming-threads) help here ?

**EDIT**: I don't think it will as this is mentioned in the DRD section of the manual.

I'm using valgrind-3.1.1 on Red Hat enterprise Linux AS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the explanation for this: my unit-test executable was linked to a [third party] library it didn't use. I re-linked it without that library and the problem went away.

Also the error was detected in `__libc_freeres()`, a function of the gnu libc that free resources at the end of the execution. The problem might lie in the library or in the glibc.
The following [Valgrind Linux-specific option](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.rareopts) can be used to avoid this error:  `--run-libc-freeres=no`. Notice this can make the leak detection less efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You are likely freeing a global variable (the address: `0x4DC4EE0` is very close to where globals live by default on Linux/x86_64).

Run the program under GDB, then do `info symbol 0x4DC4EE0`, and GDB should tell you all you need to know.

Update:
Valgrind 3.6 actually reports the global symbol already. For example, given this buggy program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int x;

int main()
{
  free(&x);
  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind 3.6 reports:

```
==18731== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==18731==    at 0x4C240E8: free /tmp/vg/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:394
==18731==    by 0x4004AA: main /home/t.c:7
==18731==  Address 0x60089c is 0 bytes inside data symbol "x"
```

Comment: Thanks, I already generated an image of my process and invoke gdb' `info address` and now also `info symbol` with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the macro `DRD_GET_DRD_THREADID` to display the thread IDs when the thread starts.  You can also give a name in the print to help.  See the [DRD Manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html)

**EDIT** Maybe I'm not specific here.. but I think you'll need to link in some valgrind libs when you build a debug version of your code (maybe with a compile option or something).  You can use the DRD_GET_DRD_THREADID from within the thread and get a name you assigned when it starts - then you can write that info to a file or to the console.  There's no way to tell DRD to print the name I don't think, so you have to use a combo.